# Does dask.s3fs actually use the cache?

Tags: amazon-s3, dask, python-s3fs

When you call `S3FileSystem().open(..., fill_cache=True)` it looks like it still goes to S3, still does the ssl handshake etc. Is this the intended behaviour that it does not cache?

Answer (score 0):

The `fill_cache` option has a very specific meaning

> ```
>     If seeking to new a part of the file beyond the current buffer,
>     with this True, the buffer will be filled between the sections to
>     best support random access. When reading only a few specific chunks
>     out of a file, performance may be better if False.
> ```

i.e., it only makes a difference when you randomly access portions of a file while that file is kept open. An initial SSL connection/handshake is required regardless, the only thing that might change is the exact range of bytes that is requested.

Also note that s3ss uses a boto `Session`, so SSL connections should in general be pooled and reused where possible.